# ListView adapter getView() being called frequently

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

In my app I have an activity `MainActivity` and in that activity 2 fragments. A `Fragment` and  a `ListFragment`.

My `Fragment` contains a `ViewGroup` that I am manipulating frequently by resetting the layout params of the children and then calling `OnLayout` to show the changes.

Ive noticed through some print statements that whenever `onLayout` in called on my `ViewGroup` also `getView()` from my list adapter for my `ListFragment` is being called. Why is this? Is there a way to avoid this? It is slowing my app down significantly.

This is similar to how I have it laid out:
[image]

Where the purple fragment contains a `ViewGroup`

Comment: Use Traceview and/or `StrictMode` to determine what, in your code, "is slowing [your] app down significantly", and tune that, rather than worrying about `onLayout()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Whats I dont know anything about that, I'm new to this.